# html images not displaying in IE

Tags: html, image, internet-explorer

I am still new to coding and have tried searching the web for my issue but haven't gotten an answer.

When I open my site up in IE it doesn't display the img files where as chrome and firefox work perfectly. All the images are either in a jpg or png format and coded in RGB as I have heard CMYK cause issues. All images are set to the correct proportions in both the file and html code and not sure what else is causing the issue. W3c validation is all ok.

Any ideas?

Here is a snippet of code from my site

```html
<div class="body">
     <div class="section">
                    <img src="images/fowlers-map.png" height="300px" width="400px" alt="map">
                    </div>
```

Comment: Can you show your CSS?

Comment: did you try and drag the image into IE? can IE display the image this way?

Comment: Yeah I have dragged each img into IE and all work fine when I do it like that.

Comment: Each img is under a different div tag, so the only parent CSS that would affect all of them is my general #img {border: 0;} tag, would that cause issues?

Answer (score 0):

May be your Windows Registry settings is altered by third party applications. Please [take a look at this.](http://www.winhelponline.com/articles/202/1/PNG-images-are-not-displayed-on-Web-sites-in-Internet-Explorer.html)

Also [take a look at this.](https://superuser.com/questions/406434/ie8-wont-display-png-images)

Comment: Would this work for JPG files as well? cause both my PNG and JPG files wont display. When I view them in IE I dont get a red X in the top corner of each image. I just get the alt text and the dimensions of the border are still intact.